# как использовать уже имеющийся текст на странице в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

На странице имеется некоторая таблица со строками

```
<tr>
<td id="config">config 1</td>
<td><div class="flag flag-ru"></td>
<td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buy" type="button" class="btn btn-info buy" id="buy-1">Купить</button></td>
</tr>
```

при нажатии на кнопку сплывает модальное окно, как мне перенести в него текст из id=config? что бы не печатать кучу модальных диалогов

Comment: [Здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target) описывается ситуация с изменением контента модального окна в зависимости от кнопки, которая его вызвала

Comment: @vihtor, то что надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $(".click").click(function () {
        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#div').hide().html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
<a href="#contentone" class="click">Загрузить</a>
<div id="contentone">Привет</div>

<div id="div">
 тут появится текст из блока #contentone
</div>
```